# if python closure is called in __main__, the closure can still access variable in function. how is it possible?

Tags: python, function, stack, closures

While reading React hock document, I found that function works differently in JavaScript than what I expected in C. I also became curious that Python function also works similarly to JavaScript and It did. Below is the code

```
def useState(initialValue):
    _val = initialValue
    def state():
        return _val
    def setState(newVal):
        nonlocal _val
        _val = newVal
    return state, setState

foo, setFoo = useState(0)
foo() # return 0; I expected that it should raise error because _val does not exist anymore after running useState function.
setFoo(1)
foo() # return 1
```

I though Python function works like function in C. What I expected was that every variable in Python function is in stack and after executing function, the stack(variables) is removed. But "setFoo" closure can still access variable in useState function and call of foo returns state. Can someone explain how Python function works or gives reference to site that explains how it works?

Comment: With your indentation, this wouldn't even compile. Please fix it to accurately reflect the situation you are asking about.

Comment: "I though Python function works like function in C. What I expected was that every variable in Python function is in stack " This isn't how Python works. Python is not C, and it is generally not helpful to think of it like C.

Comment: @juanpa-arrivillaga I fixed the code. sorry about that

Comment: Anyway, again, Python is not C, Python *has closures*, which by definition mean that free variables referenced in an enclosed scope are stored along with the execution environment and can be accessed *after* the function that created the enclosing scope is executed. This can be introspected easily in Python, look at `setFoo.__closure__`.

Comment: And again, it is not useful to think of "the stack" versus "the heap" in Python. This is an implementation detail, but in CPython all objects are allocated on a privately managed heap, *and everything is an object* (ints, floats, lists, functions, classes... everything).

Comment: So, every necessary variable is stored inside closures when useState function is called. Thank you